# Content providers: wrap with a static facade?

Tags: android, architecture, android-contentprovider

I am going through a bit of a design dilemma, I have been targeting Android 2.3.3 and have a custom implementation of a ContentProvider. I then have a class of static methods to abstract the Content provider - providing me with objects representing each entity (row) based upon my query. For a while I was very comfortable with working like this, until I started wanting to use the whole collection in a number of places, for performing "hit tests" and drawing to the screen. I then had the headache of keeping my object representations up to date, and at this point have decided I need to step back and reconsider where to take this.

As I say, I am presently using 2.3.3, and realise that in 3.0 CursorLoader overcomes a lot of the problems I have encountered. I still need to support smart phones though, so unless there will be a backport I cannot do this.

As an interim solution I started to register notifyChange listeners so that I can rebuild a collection with my original query, but this strikes me as very CPU intensive and potentially slow. I haven't yet decided whether I should roll back from using my static facade and instead use the now obsolete managedQuery call from Activity.

I therefore have two questions:

1) Is there a preferrable way to avoid the issues with working against a collection based around a contentProvider?

2) Have you any advice on working with raw cursors in an activity? Should I be making objects out of them or working with the cursor as-is? I certainly feel they should be in an AsynTask while performing the query, but after that can I use them anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, well I came to a decision and it works reliably.

> 1) Is there a preferable way to avoid
>   the issues with working against a
>   collection based around a
>   ContentProvider?

I have decided that the approach I took was correct; In my situation it is preferred to make a cache rather than maintain a cursor (managed or not) to the ContentProvider; this allows me to reuse methods and reduce the amount of code that requires testing. NotifyChange listeners are important until working on 3.0+ and that means I should guarantee the NotifyChange is called - another argument for centralising all of this code, so that it indeed triggers the changes when expected.

> 2) Have you any advice on working with
>   raw cursors in an activity? Should I
>   be making objects out of them or
>   working with the cursor as-is? I
>   certainly feel they should be in an
>   AsyncTask while performing the query,
>   but after that can I use them
>   anywhere?

In my use case I have decided it is a matter of thinking about what it is I am planning to create - avoid unnecessary work, with respect to returning unnecessary rows & fields and potentially creating unnecessary objects. If I am looking to create a map of entry names and entry IDs then I shouldn't be getting all of the other fields too. Abstracting from the collection is good but it must be lightweight and take in to account how the data is used - whether it is a one-off or may be used repeatedly. It is important that it is written for performance rather than completeness.

Comment: One consideration that has occurred to me since is that being static this approach makes the dependencies of a code implicit. Instead an object instance should be used. This will not affect its use in activities due to their creation method (not taking params) but it would affect asyncTasks and other components